# How to find a specific fact in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have just started learning Prolog and ran into some questions.

Given a location, I need to find all projects that have that location. What I have so far is shown below, but it keeps printing  false and I'm not sure why.

```
Project('Website', 'Red', 'Paris').                    
Project('Computer', 'Green', 'London').                      
Project('CPU', 'Yellow', 'Paris').
Project('Console', 'Blue', 'Berlin').

find_project(location) :- 
    findall(X, (Project(X,_,Y), Y = location),L).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog predicate names are *atoms* and thus must either start with a lower-case letter or written between single-quotes. Variables, on the other hand, must start with either an upper-case letter or an underscore. Try:

```
project('Website', 'Red', 'Paris').                    
project('Computer', 'Green', 'London').                      
project('CPU', 'Yellow', 'Paris').
project('Console', 'Blue', 'Berlin').

find_project(Location, Projects) :- 
    findall(Project, project(Project,_,Location), Projects).
```

Sample call:

```
| ?- find_project('Paris', Projects).

Projects = ['Website', 'CPU']
yes
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it was very helpful.

Comment: Another question, is there any way to print the whole project fact instead of just the name like 'website'

Comment: @saranyatadikonda you can modify the `findall/3` call to return a list of project data. E.g. `findall(project(Project,Color,Location), project(Project,Color,Location), Projects)`.